# Arithmetic operation with a void?

Tags: c++, c++11, void, arithmetic-expressions

I know that the following, if possible, would be an absolutely bad practice, but I want to know if this is possible.

The question is the following: is it possible in C++ (and in a way the compiler does not throw any warning), to perform a useless arithmetic operation with a function returning a void.

```
std::vector<int> v;
int i = 42 + v.resize(42); 
/* How to transform the last line to execute resize and to have i = 42 */
```

I know that this is stupid, but that is not the question...

Comment: Didn't test, not submitting as answer, but maybe... int i = 42 + (v.resize(42) || 0);

Comment: @isick C++ isn't JavaScript ;-P

Comment: Haha, clearly I'm out of my element. Should leave it to the C++ experts. Glad it was answered

Comment: This is silly. `void()` is not zero!

Comment: Why do you ask? Is it generated code, or inside some macro?

Comment: `(i=42) ? v.resize(42) : i ;` see my post

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I'm not sure it makes much sense, but you *could* use the [comma operator](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comma_operator) here:

```
int i = (v.resize(42), 42);
```

Comment: There possibly are good reasons `,` to use the comma operator `,` but this is not `,` one `,` of `,` them.

Comment: @Yakk: Why do you this it is not a good use case for the comma operator (imagine this being inside a template, or a macro, or some generated C++ code)? Of course as handwritten code it is awful since not very readable.

Comment: In a template, do it in more than one line -- there are no limits there.  In a macro, call a function.  In generated code, call a function.  In both generated code and macros, you can have helper stuff far away from the point of use, like: `template<typename C> std::size_t set_container_size( C& c, std::size_t s ) { c.resize(s); return s; }`, then `int i = set_container_size(v, 42);` *in the macro* or generated code.  An example of "good" uses: `for` limitations (increment two variables) and pre-C++1y `constexpr` gymnastics.

Answer (score 5):

You could use the [comma operator](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comma_operator):

```
int i = (v.resize(42), 42);
```

and with *GCC* you could use its [statement expression](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Statement-Exprs.html) extension:

```
int i = ({v.resize(42); 42;})
```

and in standard [C++11](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C++11) you could use and call an anonymous [closure](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Closure_%28computer_programming%29):

```
int i = ([&v]() {v.resize(42); return 42;}());
```

Comment: `[&]{ code }` is probably justified instead of `[&v](){ code }`.  Not that it is much better than `,`!

Answer (score 2):

Type void has no values so it may not be used in arithmetic expressions.

In my opinion the design of member function `resize` is bad. Instead of `void`it should return the object itself. In this case you could write for example

```
int i = v.resize(42).size();
```

I pointed out about this in the forum where the C++ Standard is discussed.

As for your question then you can write

```
int i = ( v.resize(42), v.size() );
```

using the comma operator.

Or maybe it would be better to separate these two calls

```
v.resize(42);
int i = v.size();
```

Comment: IMHO the statement expression extension of GCC should have been added into the standard.

Answer (score 0):

Don't see the point, but here's another way

```
std::tie(i, std::ignore) = std::make_tuple(42, (v.resize(42),1) );
```

Also you can do:

```
if ((i=42)) v.resize(42);
```

And don't forget

```
do { v.resize(42); } while (!(i=42));
```

And the favorite

```
(i=42) ? v.resize(42) : i;
```

Or (the only **serious c++** in the post)

```
int i(0);
std::vector<int> v(i=42);
```

Come on, this has no end

.....